# Regex - how to tell server to ignore unwanted characters

Tags: python, regex, server, client

I need your help with my code. I'm building client + server which will execute my raspi camera MJPG-Stream.

```
import socket
import subprocess
import re

comms_socket = socket.socket()
comms_socket.bind(('', 4244))
comms_socket.listen(20)


reg_vyraz = "Start(\d+)x(\d+)x(\d+)"


try:
 while True:
    print("Waiting for connection... (Ctrl+C to exit)")
    connection, adress = comms_socket.accept()

    print("Connected")
    try:
        while True:
            received = connection.recv(4096).decode('UTF-8') 
            if (len(received) == 0):
                break;

            m = re.match(reg_vyraz, received)

            hodnoty = m.groups()

            for cislo in hodnoty: 
                    print (cislo)                   

            print ('Received ', hodnoty, ' from the client')

        sys.stdout.write("\n")
       except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Closing connection")
        connection.close()


except KeyboardInterrupt:
 print("Closing server")
 comms_socket.close()
```

What is it doing? When client sends to the server this: Start640x450x20, server will run the stream with:
Width-640
Height-450
Fps-20

All I need is, to execute this only when I put this "Start640x450x20" into client, when I write something like "gfjlshgslsd" I need server to ignore it, not to turn down.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The entire code is correct. You have just missed 1 check.

Just check if m is None or not before calling `m.groups()`

```
if m:
    hodnoty = m.groups()
    for cislo in hodnoty: 
        print (cislo)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried it, but when I put into client something like "Ok", It still giving me Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stream.py", line 28, in <module>
    hodnoty = m.groups()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Comment: 2 questions:
1. In the post, the indentation for the inner except block is wrong.
2. You put the **print ('Received ', hodnoty, ' from the client')** in if as well right?

Comment: Oh, my bad @Dhruv Aggarwal . It works great, thanks for help.